# Two photons Rabi oscillation

Tags: spectroscopy, doppler-effect, rabi-model

Assuming we have a 2 level system (e.g. an atom with 2 energy levels) and the lifetime of the upper level can be neglected, if we make the atom interact with a laser at a fixed frequency, we would get Rabi oscillations (assume the laser is on resonance). Would we still get Rabi oscillations if the transition is driven by 2 photons, instead of one? To give a concrete example, assume we have an atom passing through an optical cavity (formed of 2 mirrors in which we have power build-up), and the frequency of the light is half the transition frequency, so the atom would need to interact with 2 photons for the excitation to take place (this is used for example in Doppler free spectroscopy). If we can adjust the time that the atom spends inside the cavity, would we still get Rabi oscillations in this case? And if so, would the treatment of the problem be the same as in the 1 photon case? Thank you!

Comment: Can I place a bet on this question? I want to place 10$ on "yes".